# Regarding implementation/usage of Background Worker

Tags: backgroundworker, multiple-instances

Ok, I've poked around and can't find a suitable answer to my question. I have a rather complicated code base that uses a Timer to initiate the creation of background worker to transmit something on regular intervals.

I am running into an issue when it calls ReportProgress:
"This operation has already had OperationCompleted called on it and further calls are illegal."

Stack Trace:

```
at System.ComponentModel.AsyncOperation.VerifyNotCompleted()
at System.ComponentModel.AsyncOperation.Post(SendOrPostCallback d, Object arg)
at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(Int32 percentProgress, Object userState)
at NAME.TX.Work(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in file.cs:line 68
at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
```

**My question is relatively simple, the function called when the timer goes off creates a new background worker, but is it actually a new background worker?**

My code (simplified because its very bulky):

```
//THIS IS THE FUNCTION CALLED BY TIMER
public void TransmitMSG(MSG msg)
{
        //Initialze _tx
        this.m_thread = new BackgroundWorker();
        m_thread.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

        //Initialize all events used by _tx
        m_thread.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(this.Work);
        m_thread.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(this.Report);
        m_thread.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.Complete);

        //Run the backgroundworker
        m_thread.RunWorkerAsync(msg);
}

//THIS IS THE WORK FUNCTION
public override void Work(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //This code is in the TX Thread
        //The sender should be the a BackgroundWorker
        BackgroundWorker _tx = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        //Check the Argument
        if (e.Argument != null && e.Argument.GetType() == typeof(MSG))
        {
            //Transmit the Argument Message
            m_THING.Transmit((MSG)e.MSG)

            //Report progress according to the result
            _tx.ReportProgress(CONSTANTS.PROGRESS.SUCCESS_TX, (MSG)e.Argument);
        }
    }
```

The Work function is an override because there is a higher handling class that allows for transmit and recieve, these two inherit from the same class so I can have common ReportProgress and Close methods.

Comment: Shot in the dark... The BGW ProgressChanged callback is called on the thread that created the BGW. In your case that would also be a background thread because you're creating it on a timer callback (unless you're using a System.Windows.Forms.Timer or a System.Timers.Timer with a SynchronizationObject). Is there any chance that thread has been killed by the time ReportProgress() gets called?

Comment: @Charles: Makes sense, I was thinking the same thing after I started looking at it...

Now my question is, what would be the best way to implement it? I'm wondering if I could get this working more efficiently with a ThreadPool. Of course then I run into the problem of passing data back and forth because the "main thread" cares about the UserState object that is being passed via ReportProgress.

Comment: From the section of code you've posted I'm not sure why you're using a BGW. Typically in Work() you would call ReportProgress() in some sort of loop, passing progressively greater values for percentProgress. Is there any reason you can't just call Work() directly from the timer callback? Work() could then call Report() and Complete() directly.

Comment: @Charles: Well, before the timer came into play the reason Work called ReportProgress is because it gave me an effective way of reporting information back to the foreground thread without closing the BackgroundWorker.

Comment: I can do that, but then my problem now is two fold:

1) If Timer calls Work directly, will Report() still be in the foreground thread? How does that work?

2) I don't think the solution is particularly elegant, which is why I am wondering now if I should take a new approach...

Should I have a single ThreadPool and a Single Transmit and a Transmit on a Timer both put the same function on the Work Queue, then that function Enqueue's status back to a common object in the Foreground Thread.

Then ManualReset can be used to signal the Foreground thread to Dequeue the status queue.

Comment: If you just use a Timer, you can marshal ReportProgress() calls to the foreground. When the class is created on the main thread, assign `SynchronizationContext.Current` to a private class field of type `SynchronizationContext` (let's call it `syncContext`). Then Work() calls ReportProgress() like this: `syncContext.Send(_ => ReportProgress(progressPercent, userData), null);`. If you want a BGW RunWorkerCompleted event equivalent you can implement that manually too.

Comment: Another option (probably easier) is to keep the Timer+BGW that you currently use, except in Transmit(), use the SynchronizationContext technique to marshal the creation & running of the BGW to the foreground thread.

Comment: If this is WinForms app, you can use System.Windows.Forms.Timer, or or System.Timers.Timer with SyncronizingObject set to your main form, and the marshalling will be handled for you.

Comment: A couple of new bits of info I've learned: if you use BGW in a non-GUI application, the Progress and Completed events do NOT get dispatched to the thread that the BGW was created on. That only works in Winforms/WPF. Also, when you do use it in a GUI app, even if you create the BGW in a background thread, the Progress and Completed events still DO get dispatched back the UI thread (this means my initial theory was wrong, if your app is a GUI app).